# Не проходит проверка на последний JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, android-shared-preferences

У меня есть сервис который с определенным интервалом подключается к серверу и сверяет последний id в БД. Если на сервере id больше, чем у меня в `preferences`, то приходит уведомление. Проблема в том, что если пользователь обновит список и получит новые записи, сервис все равно пошлет уведомление. Решил при загрузке данных брать id последнего `JSONObject` и сохранять его в `preferences`.

```
//если произошла ошибка при загрузке
        //или от сервера пришел null
        //то сохранение в БД не будет происходить
        //список будет формироваться только из сохраненных

        if (json != null || !json.equals("null"))
        {
                JSONArray messages = new JSONArray(json);
                for (int i = 0; i < messages.length(); i++)
                {
                    //берем каждый JSONObject
                    JSONObject message = messages.getJSONObject(i);
                    //берем id
                    String id = message.getString("id");
                    //сохраняем последний id 
                    //чтобы сервис не показывал ложную инфу 
                    if (i == message.length() - 1)
                    {
                        editor.putInt("lastid", Integer.parseInt(id));
                        editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

:D У вас проверка

```
if(i == message.length() - 1)
```

Не проходит, так как вы проверяете не последний `JSONObject`, а последний элемент в нем. У вас `JSONArray` назван `messages`, а не `message`

Comment: Спасибо большое, вот я растяпа невнимательный :)